# boost's macros BOOST_PP_IS_BINARY -?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

BOOST_PP_IS_BINARY is not part of the public interface of the library.
Can't find descriptions and reasons of it. How it might be used. And in what cases?

Comment: As you say, it's not part of the public interface, it's an implementation [detail](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/preprocessor/detail/is_binary.hpp). You shouldn't be using it.

Comment: I understand that it should not be using.
But I am interested in the concept. How is it used internally. In which cases it helps.